# Getting issue with Scroll the modal to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a code snippet where I'm getting issue with scroll the modal to the top position. The purpose of scroll to top modal popup, where I will show the form validation messages.

I have tried these following jQuery code.

```js
//Click event to scroll to top
 
$(".signIn-btn").click(function() {
    $("#largeModal").scrollTop(0);
});
```

```css
.modal-body {
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;  
}

.modal-body-inner {
  height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
 <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-4">Bootstrap Modal</h1>  
 <div class="row mb-4">
  <div class="col text-center">
    <h3>The Large Modal</h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">Click to open Modal</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- large modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign In</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">        
        <div class="modal-body-inner">
            <p>Modal Message At Top</p>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="inputState">State</label>
                <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                  <option selected="">Choose...</option>
                  <option>...</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                  Check me out
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary signIn-btn">Sign in</button>
        </div>    
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the element with the scroll bar, in this case `.modal-body`. Try it with

```
$(".signIn-btn").click(function() {
    $("#largeModal .modal-body").scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't write custom css for creating scrollbar because of Bootstrap4 has predefined class **`modal-dialog-scrollable`** for `modal-body` section srollable.
 And use  **`$('#largeModal .modal-body').animate({scrollTop: 0},500);`** for modal-body scroll to top.
Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content
*Note: Check this below snippet on `Full page` mode.*
I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#formID', function(){
  $('#largeModal .modal-body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  },500);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-4">Bootstrap Modal</h1>  
  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h3>The Large Modal</h3>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">Click to open Modal</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- large modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <form action="#" method="post" class="modal-content" id="formID">
      <div class="modal-header bg-light">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign In</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>      
      <div class="modal-body">        
        <div class="modal-body-inner">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <strong>Modal Message At Top</strong>
            A simple danger alert—check it out!
          </div>

          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputCity">City</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="inputState">State</label>
              <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                <option selected="">Choose...</option>
                <option>...</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="form-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                Check me out
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-start w-100">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 signIn-btn">Sign in</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>   
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Raeesh Alam, Thanks for sharing the updated code snippet and your explanation is good. 